# Help showing that this ideal is principal.

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is not for homework, and I would really like a hint please.  The question asks

> If $P = \{ 2a + (1 + \sqrt{-5})b : a, b \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}] \}$ is an ideal in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, show that $P^2$ is the principal ideal $(2)$.

I have shown that $P^2 \subseteq (2)$.  To show that $(2) \subseteq P^2$, I started by choosing some $2(m + n \sqrt{-5}) \in (2)$.  Now, if $m$ and $n$ are both even or both odd, then I can conclude that $2(m + n \sqrt{-5}) \in P^2$ after some work.  However, I cannot handle the cases of $m$ even and $n$ odd, or $m$ odd and $n$ even.  Could someone lend me a hint please?

Comment: This is already proved [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378684/norm-and-square-of-the-ideal-2-1-sqrt-5-in-the-ring-of-integers).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** As $(2)$ is principal, it suffices to prove that $2 \in P^2$. This means you only need to worry about $m=1, n=0$.

You can use

$$(1 + \sqrt{-5})(1-\sqrt{-5})-2\cdot 2=2$$