# What $I=$($2,1＋\sqrt{-5}$)$\in \Bbb{Z}[ \sqrt{-5}]$ looks like in $ \Bbb{C}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory, modules, algebraic-number-theory, integer-lattices

Let $I=$($2,1＋\sqrt{-5}$)$\in \Bbb{Z}[ \sqrt{-5}]$.
$I$ is an ideal of $\Bbb{Z}[ \sqrt{-5}]$, so it must be free $\Bbb{Z}$module of rank $2$.

But I'm having trouble to recognize the structure as $\Bbb{Z}$module.
If we write $I \cong A\Bbb{Z}＋B\Bbb{Z}$,

What can we take as $A$ and $B$ ?
(In other words, $I$ forms the lattice of $ \Bbb{C}$, **but how the lattice looks like?**)

> My try:  $2(a＋b
> > \sqrt{-5})＋(1＋\sqrt{-5})(c＋d\sqrt{-5})=(2a＋c-5d)＋(2b＋d＋c)\sqrt{-5}=2(a-b-3d)＋(２b＋d＋c)(1＋\sqrt{-5})$,
>
> thus $2$ and $1＋\sqrt{-5} $ spans $I$ with integer coefficient, and
> obviously they are linearly independent.

This is why I believe $A=2,B= 1＋\sqrt{-5} $ satisfies the condition, but I don't have confident. Is my try correct ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For a $\Bbb Z$-basis for $I$ see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378684/norm-and-square-of-the-ideal-2-1-sqrt-5-in-the-ring-of-integers).

Comment: Hint: the coefficients $2a+c-5d$ and $2b+d+c$ always have an even sum.

Comment: @Oscar Lanzi  Could you give me one more hint ?

Comment: DId you try the obvious $2\Bbb{Z}+(1+\sqrt{-5})\Bbb{Z}$ ? It suffices to check that it is closed under multiplication by $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$.

Comment: You mean, in my try, $c=a,b=d$ safies? Why can we say that ?